# Is there a way to play an MP3 or aac .pls file with Quartz Composer?

Tags: audio, streaming, mp3, audio-streaming, quartz-composer

I would like to play a radio stream in Quartz Composer.  This would be the first step in developing a new kind of radio player with (i hope) interesting visuals to accompany the audio.

Given a URL like this:

http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/KKCM.pls

I would like the composition to play the audio.

Quicktime Player will stream the station, so I'm hopeful there is a way to get Quartz Composer to do it, but I've been unable to figure it out.

**update:**  My own research has continued and I don't think there is a way to do this without writing a new Quartz Composer plug-in in objective-c.   The most promising QC patch I found was the movie importer, but I could not make that work.   If anyone knows of an existing plug-in, please chime in.

Comment: For those voting to close as off topic, Quartz Composer is a developer tool, and questions like this about how to use it seem on topic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to retrieve arbitrary network data — built-in, you can only retrieve images (`Image Importer` patch) and XML (`XML Importer` patch).

Give http://kineme.net/product/NetworkTools a try — its `HTTP Query` patch will let you download the `.pls` file; then (since it's a pretty simple format) you can parse it using either the built-in `String` patches or the built-in `JavaScript` patch.

Comment: Thanks.   Assuming, I am successful in downloading and parsing the .pls file, do you know of a way to play the audio from the streaming links contained within?  (e.g.http://2483.live.streamtheworld.com:443/KKCM_SC)

Comment: I'm accepting the answer that "no, it can't be done with built-in patches."   Thanks smokris.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to play streaming audio, either (the built-in `3D Sound Player` patch only handles local files, as does the Kineme AudioTools `File Player`).